# MVC - Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker, xmlhttprequest, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I am new in MVC and i was looking for by above error but a i can't find it.

I create a partial view to EDIT and CHANGE the data base. Partial View is  callling from INDEX.cshtml.

When I call one specific item the program below is executed at the first time in this point:

[image]

I have one field (date) with drop down. I use the datepicker function. In debug mode at the same program below is executed again because to the datepicker function and IN THIS MOMENT i receive a warning message at the command Open as shown at the second screenshot below.

[image]

**_Edit.cshtml**

Im my partial view I have the code below (part) with the datepicker. Two points. Will be this the problem (two points to datepicker ?).

Does anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

```
    @model i_Projeto.Models.Ativ_Compr_Models
    @using Newtonsoft.Json


    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

.
.
.
.
.


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#DeadLine').datepicker({
        language: 'pt-BR',
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "bottom right",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem!

remove it in partial view:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And put it in the View Father.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```